# NoneType Error in Python while using If condition

Tags: python, function, typeerror, iterable, nonetype

I am having trouble getting one of my functions in python to work. The code for my function is below:

```
def checkBlackjack(value, pot, player, wager):
    if (value == 21):
        print("Congratulations!! Blackjack!!")
        pot -= wager
        player += wager
        print ("The pot value is $", pot)
        print ("Your remaining balance is $",player)
        return (pot, player)
```

The function call is:

```
potValue, playerBalance = checkBlackjack(playerValue, potValue, playerBalance, wager)
```

And the error I get is:

```
potValue, playerBalance = checkBlackjack(playerValue, potValue, playerBalance, wager)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Since the error talks about not being able to iterate, I am not sure how to relate this to using the if condition.

Any help will really be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should ask yourself what happens when `value` is not `21`.

Answer (score 3):

You're only returning something if the condition in your function is met, otherwise the function returns `None` by default and it is then trying to unpack `None` into two values (your variables)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this question:

```
>>> a, b = None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    a, b = None
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

At this point, the problem should be clear.  If not, one could look up multiple assignment in the manual.